# How can I remove the "+" button on the new Material Design Google Calendar (or revert to an old version)?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

How can I remove the "+" button on the new Material Design Google Calendar (or revert to an old version)?  The add appointment button is large and annoying; I prefer to double tap the calendar to add appointments.

Answer (score 1):

Reverting back is easy. Just open `Settings>Apps>All Apps>Google Calendar>Uninstall updates.`